# Redirect to dashboard page while going to cache or users page in backend after upgrade to Magento 2.2.8

Tags: magento2, backend

After I upgraded a **Magento 2.2.6** to version **2.2.8**, I can not enter the Cache Management and All Users pages anymore. If I click the link in the menu I will be redirected to the dashboard page. Other pages like the Content Pages page or Products page have no problems.

Even if I place die('test') in the execute method of the controller of the page `vendor/magento/module-backend/Controller/Adminhtml/Cache/Index.php` it redirects to the dashboard. So it should go wrong before it hits this point in the code. But I don't know where to start debugging from there.

Comment: Can you able to find anything in log files?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing is being logged while this happens in the Magento, php error or nginx error log files.

Comment: Is nothing in your Magento logs too (system, debug and exception log)

Comment: No, nothing from this problem.

Comment: Can you disable all custom modules and check if it is working fine? If it is working fine we need to identify the individual module which is not compatible and do the changes accordingly

Comment: Is your problem solved? What was causing this issue?

Comment: @RajMohanR Thank you for taking the time to help me investigate this issue. The problem was indeed a third party extension. Luckily I did not needed to disable them all and go through them one by one since user1422208 did point me to the right one.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like it magento bug in vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Menu.php 
protected function _callbackSecretKey($match)

code from 2.3.0 fix it:

```
protected function _callbackSecretKey($match)
{
    $routeId = $this->routeConfig->getRouteByFrontName($match[1]);
    return \Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface::SECRET_KEY_PARAM_NAME . '/' . $this->_url->getSecretKey(
        $routeId ?: $match[1],
        $match[2],
        $match[3]
    );
}
```

OR you can disable disable Secret Key from Admin URL
System -> Configuration -> ADVANCED -> Admin -> Security -> Add Secret Key to URLs = No;

OR SQL:

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET `value` = 0 WHERE `path` = 'admin/security/use_form_key';
```

Comment: Your first response solved this problem for us. We indeed had the Mirasvit_Dashboard module installed and removing it fixed this issue. We will contact Mirasvit to solve this problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: It not Mirasvit_Dashboard bug.